# How to make an app without titlebar?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm quite new to developing on the Mac, I've only done iPhone programming until now.  I'm trying to make an app that doesn't have a titlebar.  I'd still like to allow the user to move the window around by clicking *anywhere* within the window and dragging.  Is this possible, and if so, how can I get started on something like this?  Thanks!

Comment: This is a Bad Idea. What is the reasoning for the lack of titlebar?

Comment: @Coxy: Lets just say I'm wanting to make something like a GeekTool widget.  Basically I'll have an image and some text that need to be able to move around the screen, but don't need a titlebar to function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it a borderless window.

```
[myWindow setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
```